# Pointer deep copy in C

Tags: c, pointers, copy, deep-copy

So i'm programming a circular queue in C for a school project and i have the following issue.

In some methods i work with pointers and i need to copy them. In order to have the queue work with all data types i work with a defined element_t type. This can be declared in the main.c that calls on my queue.

The thing is this copy function has to be implemented in that same main.c.
Since it is a school project we got the headers already, so the method that does the copy looks like this:

```
void element_copy(element_t *dest_element, element_t src_element)
{}
```

I can't seem to find the right code for this method, although i think i'm missing something trivial.

```
*dest_element = src_element
```

seems to just copy the src element value instead of it's 
pointee.

any help on this?

Comment: `*dest_element = src_element`  is ok, but obviously that itself indicates that you don't need a function for that.

Comment: @iharob Isn't this the correct syntax for pointer assignment => `*dest_element = &src_element;`  ?

Comment: I do need the function because the assignment requires us to copy in a different file than where it is needed.

Comment: @kkaosninja that makes dest element point to the address of src_element, i need to copy the pointee

Comment: @kkaosninja it's not, in that you are assigning to the pointee.

Comment: @Wouter that's what it does, if you want `dest_element` to point to `src_element` -> `dest_element = &src_element;` that does not copy `src_element`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly yes that's all you need

```
void element_copy(element_t *dest_element, element_t src_element)
 {
    /* prevent undefined behavior */
    if (dest_element == NULL)
        return;
    *dest_element = src_element;
 }
```

if you want you can include `string.h` and then

```
void element_copy(element_t *dest_element, element_t src_element)
 {
    /* prevent undefined behavior */
    if (dest_element == NULL)
        return;
    memcpy(dest_element, &src_element, sizeof(src_element));
 }
```

but none of the above make sense, becase a sample usage would be

```
element_t x;
element_t y;

memset(&x, 0, sizeof(x));
element_copy(&y, x);
```

which is exactly the same as

```
element_t x;
element_t y;

memset(&x, 0, sizeof(x));
y = x;
```

Comment: I think i found the problem, it was in the testcode we were given, it didn't dereference the pointers it sent through, which is why i only saw addresses.